# Pandas change of direction in a row

Tags: python, pandas

Like to get the colB from colA such that whenever the difference between two back to back rows in colA crosses a threshold (e.g 10) the value in colB flips between 0 and 1. Before the flip it should retain the old value.

[image: ColA => ColB]

So far I have this piece of code:

```
#####################################################################
## shuffle_trace()
#####################################################################

    def shuffle_trace(input, output):
        data = {'A':[0,1,2,6,8,7,15,1,2,0,4,5,3,14,13,12,0,1,2]}
        df_shuffle = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=np.int)
        df_shuffle['diffs'] = df_shuffle['A'].diff().abs()
        df_shuffle.loc[0,'diffs'] = df_shuffle.loc[0,'A']
        print(df_shuffle)
```

The output looks like:
[image: Output]

Is there any alternative of looping all the rows, here?

```
def shuffle_trace(input, output):
    thres = 10
    data = {'A':[0,1,2,6,8,7,15,1,2,0,4,5,3,14,13,12,0,1,2]}
    df_shuffle = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=np.int)
    df_shuffle['diffs'] = df_shuffle['A'].diff().abs()
    df_shuffle.loc[0,'diffs'] = 0
    df_shuffle.loc[df_shuffle['diffs'] >= thres, 'thres'] = 1
    df_shuffle['thres'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df_shuffle['B'] = (df_shuffle['thres'].cumsum()%2).astype(int)
    print(df_shuffle)
```

[image: Final Output]

Would appreciate better solution!

Comment: please share your code too

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you have the logic already, this is non-looping a vectorize solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,5,8,7,15,1,2,0,4,5,3,14,13,12,0,1,2]})
thresh = 10
df['B'] = (df.diff().abs()>thresh).cumsum()%2
df
```

Output:

```
     A  B
0    0  0
1    1  0
2    2  0
3    5  0
4    8  0
5    7  0
6   15  0
7    1  1
8    2  1
9    0  1
10   4  1
11   5  1
12   3  1
13  14  0
14  13  0
15  12  0
16   0  1
17   1  1
18   2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I get your problem, it might be solved using the following code as per my understanding:-

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if(i==0):
        #initialize first row as 0
        df.loc[i,'colB']=0
        # calculate absolute difference between the current and next row
        # and check if it is greater than thresh value
    elif(abs(df.loc[i,'colA']-df.loc[i-1,'colA'])>thresh):
        #toggle if greater
        df.loc[i,'colB'] = 1-df.loc[i-1,'colB']
    else:
        #keep same value if not
        df.loc[i,'colB'] = df.loc[i-1,'colB']
```

Optimizations are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Yashdeep for the response. I think your solution should work. Trying to figure out a solution w/o for loop.